# Bootstrap 5 Accordion button (arrow) missing

Tags: html, css, button, accordion

I've copied the example from Bootstrap 5.1 docs. When I pasted it into my .html it looked clunky (and was missing the default arrow) so I did some minor css to clean it up. As you can see in the code below I've tried the `.accordion-button::after` and `.accordion-button:not(.collapsed)::after` with a SVG background image. Still no arrow. Am I missing a reference to a document? Or am I missing some code/ID? Maybe I've accidentally written some code hiding the arrows?

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@400;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="docs/img/png/logo-no-text.png" sizes="180x180">
    <link rel="icon" href="docs/img/png/logo-no-text.png" sizes="32x32" type="image/png">
    <link rel="icon" href="docs/img/png/logo-no-text.png" sizes="16x16" type="image/png">
    <link rel="manifest" href="/docs/5.0/assets/img/favicons/manifest.json">
    <link rel="mask-icon" href="/docs/5.0/assets/img/favicons/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#7952b3">
    <link rel="icon" href="/docs/5.0/assets/img/favicons/favicon.ico">
    <link href="customcss/mainview.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>MSG Software</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row customspacing2">
                <div class="col-2 col-2custom" style="padding-top: 0.5em;">
                <h6 class="customheader1"><span id="icao"></h6><p class="customparagrahp1">Norway</p>
                <h6 class="customheader2">Active</h6>
                <p class="customparagrahp2"> <span id="time"></span></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-8 col-8custom" style="padding-top: 0.7em;">
                <h6 class="customparagrahp2"><span id="raw"></span></h6>
                <h6 class="customheader2">Precip history</h6>
                
            </div>
            <div class="col-2 col-2custom" style="padding-top: 0.5em;">
                <p class="customparagrahp2">Temp/dewpoint: <span id="temperature_celsius"></span>&deg;c / <span id="dewpoint_celsius"></span>&deg;c</p>
                <p class="customparagrahp2">Current precip: <span id="snow_inches"></span>mm./<span id="rain_inches"></span>mm.</p></p>
                <p class="customparagrahp2">Visibility: <span id="visibility_meters"></span>m</p>
                
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row customspacing2">
            <div class="col-1 col-2custom">
                <p class="customheader3">Test</p>
                <div class="accordion accordion-flush" id="accordionFlushExample">
                    <div class="accordion-item custom-spacing">
                        <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flush-headingOne">
                            <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#flush-collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseOne">
                            Test2
                            </button>
                        </h2>
                        <div id="flush-collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="flush-headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample">
                            <div class="accordion-body"><p class="customparagrahp2">Placeholder content for this accordion, which is intended to demonstrate the <code>.accordion-flush</code> class. This is the first item's accordion body.</p></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="accordion-item custom-spacing">
                      <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flush-headingTwo">
                        <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#flush-collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseTwo">
                          Test3
                        </button>
                      </h2>
                      <div id="flush-collapseTwo" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="flush-headingTwo" data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample">
                        <div class="accordion-body">Placeholder content for this accordion, which is intended to demonstrate the <code>.accordion-flush</code> class. This is the second item's accordion body. Let's imagine this being filled with some actual content.</div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="accordion-item custom-spacing">
                      <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flush-headingThree">
                        <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#flush-collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseThree">
                          Test4
                        </button>
                      </h2>
                      <div id="flush-collapseThree" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="flush-headingThree" data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample">
                        <div class="accordion-body">Placeholder content for this accordion, which is intended to demonstrate the <code>.accordion-flush</code> class. This is the third item's accordion body. Nothing more exciting happening here in terms of content, but just filling up the space to make it look, at least at first glance, a bit more representative of how this would look in a real-world application.</div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-9">
                
            </div>
            <div class="col-2 col-2custom">
                <div class="accordion" id="accordionPanelsStayOpenExample">
                    <div class="accordion-item">
                      <h2 class="accordion-header" id="panelsStayOpen-headingOne">
                        <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#panelsStayOpen-collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="panelsStayOpen-collapseOne">
                          Accordion Item #1
                        </button>
                      </h2>
                      <div id="panelsStayOpen-collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" aria-labelledby="panelsStayOpen-headingOne">
                        <div class="accordion-body">
                          <strong>This is the first item's accordion body.</strong> It is shown by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="accordion-item">
                      <h2 class="accordion-header" id="panelsStayOpen-headingTwo">
                        <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#panelsStayOpen-collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="panelsStayOpen-collapseTwo">
                          Accordion Item #2
                        </button>
                      </h2>
                      <div id="panelsStayOpen-collapseTwo" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="panelsStayOpen-headingTwo">
                        <div class="accordion-body">
                          <strong>This is the second item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="accordion-item">
                      <h2 class="accordion-header" id="panelsStayOpen-headingThree">
                        <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#panelsStayOpen-collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="panelsStayOpen-collapseThree">
                          Accordion Item #3
                        </button>
                      </h2>
                      <div id="panelsStayOpen-collapseThree" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="panelsStayOpen-headingThree">
                        <div class="accordion-body">
                          <strong>This is the third item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
            </div>   
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-2">
            1 of 2
            </div>
            <div class="col-8">
            2 of 2
            </div>
            <div class="col-2">
            3 of 3
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="customjs/custom.js"></script>
<span id="name"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

*Custom* CSS relevant to the accordion

```
.accordion-button:not(.collapsed) {
  color: #fff  !important;
  
}

.accordion-button:link, .accordion-button:visited, .accordion-button:hover, .accordion-button:active  {
  background-color: #0a2436 !important;
    color:#00ce7c !important;
    text-decoration: #00ce7c !important;
     border: 1em !important;
       border-color: #00ce7c !important;
    box-shadow: 0px !important;
    font-weight: 500;

      
}
.accordion-button {
  background-color: #0a2436 !important;
  border: 1em !important;
  font-size: 0.5em;
  color:#fff;
}


.accordion-button::after {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg viewBox='0 0 16 16' fill='%23333' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3e%3cpath fill-rule='evenodd' d='M8 0a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v6h6a1 1 0 1 1 0 2H9v6a1 1 0 1 1-2 0V9H1a1 1 0 0 1 0-2h6V1a1 1 0 0 1 1-1z' clip-rule='evenodd'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
  transform: scale(0.75) !important;
}
.accordion-button:not(.collapsed)::after {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg viewBox='0 0 16 16' fill='%23333' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3e%3cpath fill-rule='evenodd' d='M0 8a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h14a1 1 0 1 1 0 2H1a1 1 0 0 1-1-1z' clip-rule='evenodd'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
}


.custom-spacing{
  border-top: 2px;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-color: #051c2c;
}

.customspacing2{
  padding-left: 10px !important;
  padding-top: 2px;
}

.accordion-button:focus {

}
```

See missing "arrow" on picture. Any help appreciated.

[image]